# Angularjs function in ng-href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-ng-href

I want to call a function in ng-href and return the link from the function.

When I click the function it sends page to that function in url. Like:

**localhost/pageLink()**

```
<a ng-href="pagelink()" >Link</a>
```

How can i run the function and return correct link?

Comment: ng-href="{{ pagelink() }}"

Answer (score 46):

Interpolation might do the trick:

```
<a ng-href="{{pagelink()}}">Link</a>
```

**Edit:**

To anyone complaining, that this will execute the code at startup: That's exactly what it **must** do! It watches the `pagelink` method for changes and updates the `href` attribute.

The original questions was:

> How can i run the function and return correct link?

`pagelink()` should not handle routing but rather **return a string** pointing to the target route. See the [ngHref documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref).

If you want to handle routing by yourself, you should rather use `ngClick`, not `ngHref`.

Comment: I get this error: "Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop" when calling function that returns url. Why is this?

Comment: All this will do is call `pagelink()` in your controller when the page loads. Using `ng-click` without the interpolation should do the trick.

Comment: @ScottKoland The problem of using `ng-click` is you lose the abilities of `<a>` like `target="_blank"`. Open a webpage in new tab is a suffer in javascript.

Comment: I find I need to add the attribute `target="_self"` for the link to work when you click it (and not just update the URL)

Comment: It works for me. But I still do not understand why should I use interpolation with an AngularJS directive! Is it not interpolation implicitly used with A.JS directies?

Comment: **It must work without clicking**, since it's not executed on click. In this case, the method used to retrieve the string, the a-tag should point to. See the edited answer.

Comment: @Elio interpolation is totally legit here. See the documentation for the ngHref attribute: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

Comment: @ naeramarth7 now I understand it. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that `pagelink()` is at `$rootScope`, you would use `ng-click`:

```
<a href="" ng-click="pagelink()">Link</a>
```

You need the `href=""` so the browser will change the cursor on mouse over.

Comment: cannot open a webpage in new tab